# Non woking domain parameter at resolv.conf

Tags: resolv.conf

I have inserted

```
domain test
```

into resolv.conf and have then expected that

```
# getent ahosts srv
# getent ahosts srv.test
1.1.1.1         STREAM srv.test
1.1.1.1         DGRAM  
1.1.1.1         RAW
```

will both provide same results.

Any idea why is it not happening?

Thank you!

Edit:

/etc/nsswitch

```
hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

srv.test record is stored in /etc/hosts.

Comment: Where is the srv.test record? (Local hosts file, NIS, DNS?) Could we see the hosts line from `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Comment: Sure, I edited the question to provide these information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `getent` makes a system call to `getaddrinfo()` and will try each service defined in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, however, DNS resolution itself is a lower level call to `gethostbyname()` and is configured by `/etc/resolv.conf`.

In short, you can't define a fully-qualified hostname only in `/etc/hosts` because `getaddrinfo()` doesn't use search domains for hosts file look-ups. You can create a host alias in `/etc/hosts` by defining srv as;

```
1.1.1.1     srv.test srv
```

Comment: +1 because i was writing the same kind on answer when yours arrives ;)